# How to keep the text from the $_POST array on the page when you refresh?

Tags: php, arrays, post

I am building a website that lets users post text into different input boxes but my problem is that when you refresh the page or someone else goes on the page they will not be able to see the text that another person posted. So I basically want to know how you keep text on the page until someone new posts something in the input box. Here is my php code:

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
echo   $name;
```

thanks.

Comment: You can use `isset()` along with sessions if needed; *too broad.*

Comment: not even that. OP wants to share amongst multiple users. sessions would be tied to a single user, unless OP overrides the whole session system and serves up the same session ID to everyone. This is something that'd require server-side storage.

Comment: @MarcB I stand corrected; still too broad though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a storage mechanism, preferably a SQL database of your choice.

You could use `$_SESSION` to keep the data persistent, but if you want other people to be able to see what other users have posted, then your only option is to use a SQL database.

But even still, if you want to build a sort of chat box where changes are updated without refreshing the page, then you're going to want to look into websockets --

In PHP, [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/) is the application that will (efficiently) serve that sort of functionality to a page.

But, if you don't care if new changes are updated live, and if you are too lazy to use a SQL, you could just store things to a file:

```
<?php
        $oldDataChunk = json_decode(file_get_contents('/your/cache/file/that/php/can/write/to.json'));
 // get the file with all the old data. This file wont exist the first time you run it.


if($_POST){
// if there is more data POSTED, add it to what you already have - 

//EDIT: 
// The strip_tags function will prevent xss -- put there could be an advanced way to circumvent it ---
// use with caution - ! 

$oldDataChunk[] = strip_tags($_POST); // adds the new POST data to the old data
file_put_contents('/your/cache/file/that/php/can/write/to', json_encode($oldDataChunk), FILE_APPEND); //saves the data in json format for easy retrieval.

    }

print_r($oldDataChunk); 

/** 
 Outputs: 

Array ( [0] => Array( [name] => "Posted Name", [data] => "Some data that was posted" ), 
        [1] => Array( [name] => "Earlier posted name", [data] => "Etc etc etc " ) ..... 
*/
```

If you're doing something small + light, there is nothing wrong with the above, but a real application would use some SQL database for storage, and not just a file.

Comment: This is quite dangerous, because that file could end up being executed. It's best to use a database to save and get back what the user posted. Keeping and displaying unfiltered content posted by others makes the website vulnerable to XSS attacks. Please be careful!

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right -

Comment: See my edits if you want to make it secure-ish ---